# View Dataproc Job driver log in Cloud Logging

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

I cannot query Dataproc job-level logs for my job, though cluster-level logs are available.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. create a cluster using custom image based on 1.4, set up cluster properties as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/logging#enabling_job_driver_logs_in). Validation:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters describe --project <my-project> --region us-west1 <my-cluster> |grep file-backed-output
```

> dataproc:jobs.file-backed-output.enable: 'true'

```
gcloud dataproc clusters describe --project <my-project> --region us-west1 <my-cluster> |grep stackdrive
```

> dataproc:dataproc.logging.stackdriver.enable: 'true'

> dataproc:dataproc.logging.stackdriver.job.driver.enable: 'true'

2. start Dataproc job on that cluster, run commands:

```
gcloud logging read resource.type=cloud_dataproc_job --project <my-project> //returns 0 rows
```

```
gcloud logging read resource.type=cloud_dataproc_job --project <my-project> resource.labels.region=us-west1 resource.labels.job_id=<my-job>
```

> ```
> ERROR: (gcloud.logging.read) unrecognized arguments:
>  resource.labels.region=us-west1
>  resource.labels.job_id=<my-job>
>  To search the help text of gcloud commands, run:
>  gcloud help -- SEARCH_TERMS
> ```

When I look into the cluster master node, I can see the file `/etc/google-fluentd/config.d/dataproc-job-driver.conf` with a row `path /var/log/google-dataproc-job/**/driver.log`, and expected log file is available under that location.

Answer (score 3):

Did your job complete before you ran the logging commands?

I was unable to reproduce the issue with the project wide read command, but was able to reproduce the problem with the job specific command. According to https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/logging/read, the arguments all need to be enclosed in quotation marks - so your command should instead look like:

```
gcloud logging read "resource.type=cloud_dataproc_job resource.labels.region=us-west1 resource.labels.job_id=<my-job>" --project=<my-project>
```

I will file a bug to ensure the documentation is correct to reflect the correct quotation marks.

Comment: I was able to find some log entries using the command `gcloud logging read "resource.type=cloud_dataproc_job" --project <my-project>`
But when I clarified the job UUID (tried failed and running jobs after more than 2 mins after job start date), it returned 0 rows:
`gcloud logging read "resource.type=cloud_dataproc_job resource.labels.region=us-west1 resource.labels.job_uuid=<running-or-failed-job-uuid>" --project <my-project> `

Comment: Does this apply to successful jobs as well? Or just failed/running? There are 2 ids for a job - the job id and the job uuid. I made the mistake of setting job_uuid to the job id when testing this out and got no results - please be certain that the right resource is being used with the correct id.